# How would the representation of a circle in 4 dimensions?

Tags: mathematics, geometry, spacetime-dimensions

We know that the representation of a square in three dimensions is a cube, and in four dimensions is a tessaract or, hyper cube.

With this, How would be the representation of a circle in four dimensions?

Comment: Too short for answer: it's a hyper sphere! Or 3-sphere! Or glome! Also, the tags are mind-blowing.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a question about physics...

Comment: What I want is an image or an explanation about would be an a n-sphere. Like this explanation of hyper cube: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/07/Hipercubo.svg

Comment: Are these 2-D representations of "n>3"-D objects really worth anything? Not for me, really, but maybe I'm just dumb...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows clear insufficient research effort.

Answer (score 2):

The term you are looking for is either "hypersphere" or "n-sphere". [Pictures and mathematical description on the wiki site](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere)

Answer (score 2):

Naively, a hypersphere. But it all depends on how you actually generalize the concept of a circle to higher dimensions.

For cube, a dimension-independent definition would be $|x_i|<a$ if $x_i$ are components of a $n$-vector in an orthogonal coordinate frame. For a hyperoctahedron, it would be $\sum |x_i|<a$. And for a hyperball, $|\vec{x}|<R$ (hyper-ball in 2D is a disc). A circle is a boundary of a disc, and a hypersphere is a boundary of a hyperball (change $<$ into $=$). However, you could also generalize a circle to a hyper-torus. That's why I'm saying it depends on the definition you adopt for your object.